# Does a ROTOR Bikes 3DF or 3D+ axle/spindle remove?

Tags: crankset, rotor

Anyone know if it's possible to remove the axle from the left non-drive side ROTOR 3DF XC3 crank arm? It has a spline, so it looks like maybe a tool would do it, but probably proprietary? Or maybe it's fused in there somehow. Either way, any knowledge will help. I asked one sales person who said you can't, and took it to a shop where they said maybe, but that I would need a proprietary tool. ACTUALLY, all I really need in my case is to unscrew the ring to remove it to allow for custom refinishing. I might attempt to make something. [image]

The 3D+ looks about the same.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a removal tool original from ROTOR. You will find it here:
https://www.rotorstore.eu/product/rotor-3d-non-drive-side-cap-removal-tool/?v=fa868488740a

[image: Rotor original removal tool]

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked with these for a while but my memory suggests that the ring can be undone with a quality pin spanner (one that locks to a size). By itself, that won't allow you to remove the spindle but that's not what you are asking (it turns out).

The UK distributor is VeloTech Services and they are knowledgeable, a small company and very helpful. If you sling them an email, they will give you the information you need.

I hope that helps you find the solution.